# Sum corresponding elements between two multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, addition, array-map

Suppose that I have two arrays, and I want to add the corresponding elements.

```
$v_4 = [
    [1, 2, 3], 
    [4, 5, 6],
];
$v_5 = [
    [7, 8, 9], 
    [10, 11, 12], 
];
```

How should I construct an addition function to add across these arrays to get:

```
[
    [8, 10, 12], 
    [14, 16, 18],
]
```

I know I need to utilise [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-map.php) somehow, but I am unsure how to proceed in this multidimensional case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$new = array();
foreach(array_map(null, $v_4, $v_5) as $var) {
    $data = call_user_func_array("array_map", array_merge(array(null) , $var));
    $new[] = array_map("array_sum", $data);
}
print_r($new);
```

[See Live DEMO](https://eval.in/33175)

The Example above is only limited to 2 arrays .. if you have more like `10` .. you can use this function with a little modification

```
print_r(array_sum_colums($v_4,$v_5,$v_6));
```

Or

```
print_r(array_sum_colums(array($v_4,$v_5,$v_6)));
```

[See Live DEMO](https://eval.in/33177)

Function

```
function array_sum_colums() {
    $args = count(func_get_args()) == 1 ? func_get_arg(0) : func_get_args();
    $arg = call_user_func_array("array_map", array_merge(array(null),$args));
    $new = array();
    foreach($arg as $var) {
        $data = call_user_func_array("array_map", array_merge(array(null), $var));
        $new[] = array_map("array_sum", $data);
    }
    return $new ;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain `array_merge(array(null), $var)`? What is the importance of `array(null)` and what does `$var` contain at that point?

Comment: array_merge only takes array ..... `array(null)` is a way of adding a null values to the array. You can use `var_dump($var)` to see what var contains

Answer (score 0):

Synchronously isolate respective rows from both arrays, then sum the columns within each grouped payload of row data.

The outer call of `array_map()` isolates the rows from each array, the inner call of `array_map()` isolates the columns from the grouped rows.

Code ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bBssT))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn(...$row) =>
            array_map(
                fn(...$col) => array_sum($col),
                ...$row
            ),
        $v_4,
        $v_5
    )
);
```

---

A less dynamic, more performant approach which is suitable for your exact sample data and much easier to read is to simply use nested loops and synchronously iterate each element in each of the two arrays.  Of course this is only suitable because both arrays have exactly the same structure.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Tbu2D))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($v_4 as $i => $row) {
    foreach ($row as $k => $v) {
        $result[$i][$k] = $v + $v_5[$i][$k];
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

---

In fact, if you don't mind modifying the first array as you iterate, you can simply add the corresponding values from the second array directly onto the first array elements. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/99I9H))

```
foreach ($v_4 as $i => &$row) {
    foreach ($row as $k => &$v) {
        $v += $v_5[$i][$k];
    }
}
var_export($v_4);
```