# Multidimensional array multiplication

Tags: php, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, multiplication

Suppose I want a code in PHP that replicates matrix multiplication, where my matrices look like:

```
$matrix_1 = array(array(1,2), array(3,4))
```

The number of subarrays (**2**) is equivalent to the number of columns in the matrix, whereas the number of elements in each subarray (**2**) represents the number of rows in the matrix.

The code would need to:

- Account for matrices of different dimensions.
- Recognise when two matrices cannot be multipled (where the number of columns in matrix A is not the same as the number of rows in matrix B).
- Possibly account for scalar multiplication, where each element of a matrix is multiplied by a constant.

I have attached slides [here](http://www.slideboom.com/presentations/779010/slides?pk=4108-d50c-27ae-e9cc-094f-9aa0-43a4-9e2d) that explain what the code should achieve (with two examples).

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: It may or may not be my homework! I've tried googling but most solutions are a bit messy?  Suppose I should give it a go myself though!

Comment: And what have you done so far?

Comment: Very inelegant stuff so far - simply splicing the arrays and forming new arrays out of them. Also I don't have a general solution yet for all matrix dimensions - and am working mostly with square matrices at the moment.

Comment: @user2468585, use link above

Comment: *"Suppose I should give it a go myself though!"* <- yes you should. that is expected before asking because you should as a programming question, that means you've got a problem programming something. Also the description "messy" is pretty subjective. What is messy for somebody might not be messy for somebody else, so we just can not understand *your problem*. And please don't link some flash sites, you can create images and add them to your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multidimensional array addition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014239/multidimensional-array-addition) - I can't hinder myself of getting the impression you are really lazy and not programming at all.

Comment: Maybe I am busy so I am checking online to see if anyone else knows the answer first? Don't be presumptuous. But I'll post what I have for this as an answer later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my (long-winded) solution. I'm going to try to see if I can simplify this in places.  Note that:

- This solution does not account for scalar multiplication, but this is relatively easy to incorporate if you wanted to include it. Assume a scalar is a one-element array - in which case, in the `else` command simply include a `count()` command to recognise if one (or more) of arrays is a scalar and apply a multiplication function accordingly using `array_map`.
- I am assuming that the arrays follow matrix form - e.g. one column
  cannot have more elements than another. You can account for this
  formally by making sure each subarray has the same number of
  elements.

**The code:**

```
<?php

// FUNCTIONS

function mul($x, $y){
    return ($x * $y);
}

// Example Arrays

$array_1 = array(array(1,4,7), array(2,5,8), array(3,6,9));
$array_2 = array(array(7,6,4), array(5,8,1), array(4,3,2));

// Check for row/column equivalence

$array_1_cols = count($array_1);
$array_1_rows = count($array_1[0]);
$array_2_cols = count($array_2);
$array_2_rows = count($array_2[0]);

// Check to see if matrix multiplication is possible

if($array_1_cols == $array_2_rows) {

$m_cols = $array_2_cols;
$m_rows = $array_1_rows;

$array_3 = array();
$col_index = 1;

// Start loop for each column of the new matrix

while($col_index <= $m_cols) {
$m_col_index = $col_index - 1;
$sub_array[$col_index] = array();

// Start loop for each row of the new matrix

$row_index = 1;
while($row_index <= $m_rows) {
$m_row_index = $row_index - 1;

// Auxiliary array for each row of A
$a_row[$row_index] = array();

$a_index = 1;
while($a_index <= $array_1_cols) {
$start_p = $a_index - 1;
$el_part_[$a_index] = $array_1[$start_p];
$el_part_[$a_index] = $el_part_[$a_index][$m_row_index];
array_push($a_row[$row_index], $el_part_[$a_index]);
++$a_index;
}

// Array for columns of B

$b_col[$col_index] = $array_2[$m_col_index];

// Build matrix C - defined over the rows of A and the columns of B

$c_part[$row_index][$col_index] = array_map('mul', $a_row[$row_index], $b_col[$col_index]);

$c_el[$row_index][$col_index] = array_sum($c_part[$row_index][$col_index]);

array_push($sub_array[$col_index], $c_el[$row_index][$col_index]);

// End row loop

++$row_index;
}

array_push($array_3,$sub_array[$col_index]);

++$col_index;
}

print_r($array_3);

} else {

echo "This is not possible!";

}


?>
```